# Prevent results of GetGeometry from disappearing after AJAX call

Tags: openlayers, ajax

In my ongoing mission to try to find a way to zoom into a specific area of a map (in this case a DMA), I am first trying to get the coordinates of a selected point that will be accessible to me for use as coordinates to recenter my map in OpenLayers.  More specifically, I am trying the replicate the example in OpenLayers found here:  https://jsfiddle.net/1Lpqxc53/

I am able to populate the div called "result" with the getGeometry feature but unlike the example I then lose this data when the page refreshes.  I need this data to persist so that can then access these coordinates to recenter my map.

Below is my html code and javascript code.  If there is any easier way to recenter my map based on the coordinates of a WFS/WMS layer created in GeoServer, I would be open to alternatives as I am not sure that my approach is best.

OL_index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name=description content="">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Openlayer Station Maps</title>

    </script>
    <!--two versions of jquery uploaded (jquery.min.js)-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!--external openlayers stylesheet-->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">

    <!--additional style parameters-->
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
      }

    </style>


  <!--third party openlayers javacript library-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/build/ol.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


  <h2>My Map</h2>
  <br>
  <br>
  <form name="myform">
      <input type="text" id="DMA" value="501">
      <input type="button" id="dma_change_button" value="Set DMA">
     <button id="view-json">View JSON</button>
  </form>
  <br>

<div id="map" class="map">
     </div>
    <br>
   <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
   <br>
   <div id="result"><p><b>Geometry:</b></p></div>



<!--import compiled openlayers javascript libraries-->
        <script src='/OL_index.js')></script>
```

Here is my OL_index.js page (I try to replicate the example code starting with the "feats" variable):

```
  //set default lon and lat

  var center_Lon=-95.71;
  var center_Lat=37.09;


  var map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
         new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
                        center: olProj.fromLonLat([center_Lon, center_Lat]),
        zoom: 4
      })
    });



  var view = map.getView();

    //create station contours based on selected DMA
    var viewparameters='D:'+document.forms["myform"]["DMA"].value;
    var wmsSource= new ImageWMS({
      url: 'aws_url:8080/geoserver/aws_postgres/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'aws_postgres:aws_postgres_station_groups',
                                   'viewparams':viewparameters,
                                    'TILED':true
                                   },
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
      serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
    var station_contours = new ImageLayer({
                     source: wmsSource

                  });
    station_contours.setOpacity(0.7);
    station_contours.set("name", "station_contours");


    //  add the layers to the map
    map.addLayer(station_contours);



$("#dma_change_button").click(function() {

               $('#info').empty();

               function resetContours(){

                    var viewparameters='D:'+document.forms["myform"]["DMA"].value;
    station_contours.getSource().updateParams({'LAYERS':'aws_postgres:aws_postgres_station_groups', 'viewparams':viewparameters});


                  }
               resetContours();

    });



//function to get attributes when clicking on cell on map and then populate INFO div
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";


     var viewResolution = /** @type {number}*/  (view.getResolution());
     console.log(viewResolution);
     var url = wmsSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
       evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
       {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});


     if (url) {
       fetch(url)
         .then(function (response) {return response.text(); })
         .then(function (html) {
            console.log(html);
               if(html!=='[object Object]'){
                    $('#info').html(html) ;
               }
         });
     }
   });



var feats = [
  new Feature(new Point(olProj.fromLonLat([-95.54967, 38.70250]))),
  new Feature(new Point(olProj.fromLonLat([-95.54967, 39.70250]))),
  new Feature(new Point(olProj.fromLonLat([-95.3476, 39.12765]))),
  new Feature(new Point(olProj.fromLonLat([-95.85467, 38.935])))
];
var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: feats
});
var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);



var viewJson = document.getElementById('view-json');
var selectInteraction = new olInteraction.Select({multi: true});
map.addInteraction(selectInteraction);

var viewJson = document.getElementById('view-json');
var toGeoJSON = new GeoJSON();

viewJson.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  result.innerHTML = ' ';

  var selectedFeatures = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
  selectedFeatures.forEach(function(feature){
    console.log(feature.getGeometry());
    $('#result').append(toGeoJSON.writeGeometry(feature.getGeometry()));

  });
}, false);

console.log(selectedFeatures);







//add zoom control button and then create the boundaries that are zoomed to boundaries
var zoomToExtentControl = new ZoomToExtent({
  extent: [-11243808.051695308, 4406397.202710291, -4561377.290892059, 6852382.107835932]
});
map.addControl(zoomToExtentControl);


//go through every control at the map layer and remove OpenStreetMap attribution before zooming in
var controls = map.getControls();
var attributionControl;
controls.forEach(function (el) {
    console.log(el);
  console.log(el instanceof olControl.Attribution);
  if (el instanceof olControl.Attribution) {
    attributionControl = el;
  }
});
map.removeControl(attributionControl);
```

Comment: Why are you saving your AJAX call result as in a HTML element and not in global JavaScript variable?